# PostgreSQL hierarchy(?) structure

Tags: postgresql, hierarchy

Please excuse my ignorance.  I'm certain this is a FAQ, but I don't know the terminology well enough to know what to look for.

My company uses the following structure in terms of territory (example following):

```
  Customer -> Market -> Area -> District -> Region
  XYZ Co. -> Queens -> NYC -> Mid Atlantic -> Northeast
```

Each customer has only one market.  Each market has only one district, and so forth.  (I'm not sure if you'd call that one-to-many or many-to-one.  I don't want to label it incorrectly).

This is how I have things set up right now:

```
create table region(
id           int  not null primary key,
name         varchar(24)
);

create table district(
id           int  not null primary key,
name         varchar(24),
region_id    int  references region(id) on update cascade
);

create table area(
id           int  not null primary key,
name         varchar(24),
district_id  int  references district(id) on update cascade
);

create table market(
id           int  not null primary key,
name         varchar(24),
area_id      int  references area(id) on update cascade
);
create table customer(
id         int  not null primary key,
name       varchar(32),
sixweekavg numeric, 
market_id  int  references market(id) on update cascade
);
```

Right now I have an opportunity to improve that setup as I'm more or less rewriting the site.  I looked at this popular page:
[What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)
And I'm sure that my best scenario lies there, but I don't know enough to figure out which one.

It's a reporting site, so there are way more reads than writes.  Some of my pages show aggregated data at each level, customer through region (and top, too).  So right now on a page that shows district-level data I would write something like:

```
select d.name, sum(sixweekavg) as avg from customer c
  inner join market m on m.id = c.market_id
  inner join area a on a.id = m.area_id
  inner join district d on d.id = a.district_id
  group by d.name order by d.name;
```

Pretty standard stuff, right?  I'm sure a whole separate conversation could be had about materialized views, but for now I'd like to explore a better option for structuring the hierarchy (if that's even the correct term for this).

So given the following summary

- PostgreSQL (it can be assumed this will not change)
- Fixed hierarchy (my employer may at some point add or remove a tier, but every row in the customer table will always have the same number of "parents")
- Significantly more reads than writes

Is there one method that may be better than the others for setting this up?

**ltree**

I did look at ltree, but I'm not quite sure how that would work.  On pages where a user can select a district, for example, I query the district table for the names of each district.  I had the idea to add an ltree column in my customers table which would hold the hierarchy, but still maintain the other tables.  Is that a feasible and reasonable approach? I've searched for real-world examples of ltree but came up short - most that I found were designed for a random number of parent/child nodes, like a threaded comment section.

I appreciate your help and your patience!

Comment: But one Region can have multiple Districts, one District multiple Areas, one Area multiple Markets and one Market multiple Customers? In this case you are talking one to many. But you are reading in inverse order.

Comment: Why you need `UPDATE CASCADE` ? you shouldn't be changing the ids.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, I shouldn't.  But it's happened once, so I keep that there just in case.